# How do you test ETL jobs for large tables?

Tags: etl, amazon-redshift

I'm in the middle of designing ETL jobs for large fact and dimension tables, but am rather curious as to what would be the best way to test them. I have dev, test, and prod environments setup to test, but I don't think there is as much memory in the former 2 environments as there is in prod.

Some of the fact tables are rather big, spanning to around 1 TB.

So what's typically a good way to make sure a job is designed and tested properly before moving to production?

Comment: It's called multiplication. Or precisely linear extrapolation. Basically you do subsets in your test and then do simple math to predict that your ok.

Comment: Are you running a number of Redshift clusters or only one? You can start a cluster in the same size and even same data as the productions one with "Restore from Snapshot", run your tests and delete the test cluster at the end of the test.